# Fetch Precise User Location/Landmark on a Web Application

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, web-applications, geolocation

I am working on a logistics application, that requires me to fetch user location, most especially user's address or closest landmark in order to match two individuals within the same location. I have checked out the Geolocation API to get the latitude and longitude. I made use of the watchPosition().

I also used a Reverse GeoCoding API to decode the latitude and longitude to a human-readable address, but the address I am getting is 2 hours far from my location, which means the latitude and longitude isn't precise or accurate.

I need help on how I can get the right user location on a web application. Or if it could be achieved on the backend.

Backend - Java SpringBoot
Frontend - React JavaScript

Comment: Are you using the IP address? If so, that isn't supposed to be accurate as many people use the same IP. If you want the location of a user, ask them.

Comment: I am not using the IP address, I am using Geolocation API. I understand the option of having to ask them, but I want to be able to determine their accurate location within the web app.

Comment: IP address geolocation won't be able to fetch "precise" user location as requested.